# Uncaught Error: TypeError: 100: type 'JSInt' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, casting

```
void main() {
 String num = "50";
  int quantity = 2;
  num = (int.parse(num) * quantity) as String;
  print("num is "+num);
}
```

This is giving me error

Actually i want to convert a string to numerical value and perform calculations and update the string back with the updated value.

```
// Assume the intial value of 
// item.quantity = 1, item.cost = 20

-----------------------------------------------------------------

item.quantity++;
item.cost = (int.parse(item.cost) * item.quantity) as String;

-----------------------------------------------------------------

====================================================
expected result item.cost = 40 
generated result is 2020
====================================================
```

Comment: You can use `.toString()`. But I would seriously consider storing your numbers as numbers rather than strings, so that you don't have to convert back and forth every time you need to do some calculation on your numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `toString` you create a new `String` value. By casting `as T` you tell the compiler that an unknown value you want as `T` value.

```dart
void main() {
 String numer = "50";
  int quantity = 2;
  numer = (num.parse(numer) * quantity).toString();
  print("sum is $numer"); // sum is 100
}
```

> **Note:** avoid use names which is reserved by system to avoid conflict.